# Where is $MA$ more relevant than $\exists BPP$?

Tags: complexity-classes, promise-problems, probabilistic-complexity

NP can be defined as the class of languages which admit sets of certificates which are in P. The definition could be as follows.

A language $L$ is in $NP$ iff there is a set $C=\left\{ x,c\right\}$ and a polynomial $p$ such that:

- $x\in L\rightarrow \exists c ((x,c)\in C)$
- $x\notin L\rightarrow \forall c ((x,c)\notin C)$
- $(x,c)\in C\rightarrow |c|\leq p(|x|)$
- $C\in P$

This doesn't work for MA, because the probabilistic verifier there is not required to decide any BPP language: when $x\notin L$ it always refuse with bounded error, but when $x\in L$ the verifier is required to accept with bounded error only for one certificate, for all the others it could answer just randomly and thus violate the BPP promise.

What about the following class then?

A language $L$ is in $MA^*$ iff there is a set $C=\left\{ x,c\right\}$ and a polynomial $p$ such that:

- $x\in L\rightarrow \exists c ((x,c)\in C)$
- $x\notin L\rightarrow \forall c ((x,c)\notin C)$
- $(x,c)\in C\rightarrow |c|\leq p(|x|)$
- $C\in BPP$

It is clearly $MA^* \subseteq MA$ but not the opposite (at least not trivially). My questions are  as follows. Is $MA^*$ somewhat known and studied? And why is $MA$ more relevant?

**UPDATES**

A previous version of this question presented above asked about a complexity class I called $MA^*$, which has been recognized by users to be $\exists BPP$.

The difference between $MA$ and $\exists BPP$ is that in the latter class the probabilistic verifier decides a BPP language; while the probabilistic verifier in $MA$,  when $x\in L$, is required to accept with bounded error only for one certificate and can answer just randomly for all the others, thus violating the BPP promise.

What is the natural reason to allow this "strange" power to the class? E.g. an $MA$ language which is not (trivially) in $\exists BPP$ would answer the question. More generally, in which contexts the class $MA$ comes up naturally but $\exists BPP$ wouldn't (trivially) work?

P.S. For now, I'm answering me as follows. A set $C$ of certificates $x,c$ for $x \in L$ makes sense only in reference to a verification procedure for $(x,c)$. If the verifier is probabilistic, and we want bounded error, there could be some $x,c$ that aren't decided. For $x \notin L$, it remains defined that $(x,c) \notin C$, or soundness is compromised. But what should define $(x,c) \in C$ for $x \in L$, if not the verification procedure itself? So in this sense $MA$ is more natural than $\exists BPP$, because $MA$ doesn't assume $C$ before the verification procedure.

Comment: In other words, $\mathrm{MA}^*=\exists\cdot\mathrm{BPP}$.

Comment: I think I have encountered many times this dot product notation for complexity classes, but I am not sure of its meaning. Could you link me to a definition?

Comment: The dot notation does not mean much by itself, it just denotes an application of the $\exists$ *class operator* to BPP. You can actually write it as just $\exists\mathrm{BPP}$. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/a-good-reference-for-complexity-class-operators.

Comment: By the way, since BPP is closed under Turing reductions, you also have $\mathrm{MA^*=NP^{BPP}}$.

Comment: I cannot upvote yet so: thanks! A last question: do you have in mind a "natural" MA language which is not (trivially) in MA*?

Comment: I can’t recall any natural problem in *either* MA or $\mathrm{MA}^*$ that’s not already in NP or BPP. However, MA comes up naturally in various structural results in complexity theory such as $\mathrm{EXP\subseteq P/poly\implies EXP=MA}$, and these are not known to hold with $\mathrm{MA}^*$.

Comment: This class is in the zoo, [here](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:E#existsbpp). It notes, as you may already have, that $\text{NP}\subseteq \text{MA}^\ast=\text{NP}^{\text{BPP}}\subseteq \text{MA}$.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen WHy is it in NP^RP?

Comment: @1.. Correction: the minimization of d-DNNF Boolean circuits is in $NP^{RP}$. A d-DNNF circuit has enough structure to allow a $\text{coRP}$ identity test. Therefore, the NP Machine can supply the smaller circuit, and then the RP oracle can verify that the circuit supplied behaves identically to the given circuit. This problem is therefore in $NP^{RP}$. (I have deleted the previous comment).

Comment: Ok I didn't realize rp was not low for np.

Comment: Since my comment above now fits the revised question (“in which contexts the class MA comes up naturally but ∃BPP wouldn't (trivially) work”), I expanded it to an answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: The promise problem stoquastic 6-SAT (essentially, estimating the ground state energy of a frustration-free stoquastic Hamiltonian where each term is 6-local) is MA-complete. [See Bravyi, Bessen and Terhal](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611021v1).

Comment: @PeterShor Since this is a promise problem, you mean that it is **promiseMA**-complete, right? MA is a semantic class and, similar to BPP, is not known to have complete problems. But anyway, if you have an interesting answer to the OP’s question, please post it as an answer, not as a comment directed to me.

Comment: Based on the responses I am getting, I’m beginning to suspect that my [comment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48338/where-is-ma-more-relevant-than-exists-bpp#comment107439_48338) above is prone to misunderstanding. It only means what it literally says: that I couldn’t think of any interesting problems in MA off the top of my head. It was not at all my intention to suggest that no such problems exist.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes, I meant promise-MA-complete. But by the very nature of MA, it seems that you can't have MA-complete problems, just promise problems that are promise-MA-complete.  And before I post it as an answer, I want to check that there aren't any promiseMA*-complete problems.

Comment: @PeterShor The whole difference between MA and MA* is predicated on the difference between promiseBPP and BPP. How do you define promiseMA* so that it is different from promiseMA?

Comment: PromiseMA* would be like promiseMA with the difference that we can always answer with bounded error for certificates of yes instances.  This could work for stoqsat, as certificates are discrete strings. Wouldn't that mean MA=MA*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\mr{\mathrm}$First, standard derandomization assumptions (the existence of a language in $\mr E$ that requires circuit size $2^{\Omega(n)}$) imply $\mr{promise\text-BPP=promise\text-P}$, hence
$$\mr{MA=\exists BPP=NP},$$
thus any difference between the two classes is likely just an artifact of our incomplete knowledge.

Having said that, there are several results in complexity theory involving $\mr{MA}$ that are not known to hold for $\exists\mr{BPP}$. In particular, there is a group of results of the form
$$\begin{align*}
\mr{PP\subseteq P/poly}&\implies\mr{PP=MA},\\
\mr{PSPACE\subseteq P/poly}&\implies\mr{PSPACE=MA},\\
\mr{EXP\subseteq P/poly}&\implies\mr{EXP=MA},\\
\mr{NEXP\subseteq P/poly}&\implies\mr{NEXP=MA}.
\end{align*}$$
(The first three results are due to [Babai, Fortnow & Lund](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01200056), the last one is due to [Impagliazzo, Kabanets & Wigderson](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00024-7).)

If you allow me larger time bounds, an often quoted related result is that
$$\mr{MA\text-EXP\nsubseteq P/poly}$$
(here, $\mr{MA\text-EXP=MA\text-TIME}(2^{n^{O(1)}})$ is the exponential analogue of $\mr{MA}$). In fact, this result can be [improved](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/40768), nevertheless it is not known to be true for $\mr{NEXP^{BPP}}$ (which is the exponential analogue of $\exists\mr{BPP}=\mr{NP^{BPP}}$).